# Can magit stage a hunk / selected lines in 'diff-mode'?

Tags: magit, diff-mode

Is it possible to stage the current hunk or selected lines of the hunk in `diff-mode`?

For example, when in `diff-mode`, what command can I run to stage the current hunk?

Comment: This is a yes/no question.  You probably should rewrite it to clarify what additional information you'd want to see in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But maybe `diff-mode` itself can.

Comment: Ah, I thought this is something magit would handle, when in `diff-mode` all the commands containing the word "stage" are from magit, so I assumed regular diff mode couldn't do this.